# Rspec Ruby 1.9 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

While executing command to test my whole app im getting the following error:

```
rspec spec/
/Users/ivankutsarov/railstwitter/twitter/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `subject' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/ivankutsarov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: It looks like you have a `subject` that is placed in the wrong scope. Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Please, show your `/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` file.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. Here is the code example you asked:
http://pastebin.com/KcyMVJsw